# Structure and dependencies of cross-platform CMake project

Tags: c, cmake, cross-platform, cross-compiling, dependency-management

What is the right way to include external dependencies into CMake project? I've seen in some projects and dependencies, people add dependency as a git submodule, some find-scripts ExternalProject and package managers (conan).

So, the project is cross-platform (Windows, Android, in perspective iOS, macOS, Linux and others) and needs cross-compiling. The project is closed source, so user gets compiled binary. Cross-compiling is very important. Some of platforms require special dependencies (example: desktop needs GLFW).

One of solutions I think about: write a script (I think, python, because I need ability to compile project as in Windows as in Linux), which will compile all the dependencies for given platform (toolchain), put them in right folders and generate a script with paths to the libraries.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You ask what is the best (right) structure for your project ... but there is **no best** CMake project's structure. You talk about cross-compiling, but this gives a little limitations as CMake itself supports cross-compiling. I see you know some possible approaches, so simply choose one of them and try to follow it. When you will face with a problem (and reveal some additional requirements of your project), then ask about this **specific problem**. We would gladly to help you in that case.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, is my last idea good? Maybe there is some improvements for it or some recommendations?

Comment: Actually, I don't see how the last sentence (with a script) correlates with remaining question post. Approaches "git submodule" and ExternalProject implies dependencies to be in a source form, why do want to compile these dependencies?

Comment: @Tsyvarev, I think to put dependencies as submodules, but I still need to include them to the project somehow. `add_subdirectory` seems to be bad, because I had some problems with `libwebp` which takes long time to build. Also I need to use luajit (which uses very complex Makefile). I think it will be easier to build all dependencies with script and put binaries and headers somewhere, and add them to CMakeLists of the project.

Comment: Yes, in most cases pre-built dependencies are better.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, thank you!